# How to ensure unique properties on Gremlin vertices?

Tags: graph, gremlin, amazon-neptune, gremlin-server

Does Gremlin support unique properties other than ID property?

Trying to figure out if there's an equivalent in Gremlin to defining a field unique in Postgres for example.

I could always query the graph to see if the property exists first, I'm trying to figure out if there's a more efficient elegant way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is something that Apache TinkerPop leaves up to the database implementor, and it does vary by implementation. I see you tagged the question with `amazon-neptune`. Currently Neptune only enforces the unique ID constraints for vertices and edges.

It's possible in a future release that additional schema constraint capabilities will be added, but at the present time you would have to monitor/control that in your application logic.